# Load data from Hbase with a Pig script without knowing the number of fields

Tags: hbase, apache-pig

In Hbase, I have for each row the columns:

```
u1:chararray, u2:chararray, ..., un:chararray
```

in a column family named u (from the utable)
The number n can be different for each row. I would like to load all these columns in tuples without naming them all (for example by using the * character) but I don't really see how to do so.

For the time being I create my tuples with the following line:

```
qoe1 = LOAD 'hbase://utable'
       USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('u:u1, u:u2, u:u3', '-loadKey true')
       AS (ID:chararray, u1:chararray, u2:chararray, u3:chararray);
```

But as I told before, it is unsatisfying because I can only load a fixed number of columns.

Any idea?

Comment: What's the maximum n?

Comment: The maximum for n is 25.

Comment: I'm not familiar/using HBase, but isn't there a form that works with a map? -- `HBaseStorage('u:*','-loadKey') AS (id, u:map[])`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. Solved it with the following: If you know the column family names, you can load all columns that fall under a column family from HBase into Pig using the following. 
Basically it comes down to putting all columns (using *) in a map:

```
result = LOAD    'hbase://your_table_name'
         USING   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('u:*', '-loadKey true') 
         AS      (id:bytearray, u:map[])
;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is little late to answer this question but its worth sharing the knowledge to the world of beautiful developers who always believe in StackOverflow.
@Sander van den Oord's answer is perfect to load the data from HBase table.

To do further manipulation with the data you should need some more techniques. There are some useful functions available with a custom udf jar called Pigitos. You can download it from [here](http://hakunamapdata.com/pigitos-in-action-reading-hbase-column-family-content-in-a-real-world-application/).

Here is the code snippet.

```
register hdfs:///hdfs/location/of/Pigitos-1.0.jar
DEFINE MapEntriesToBag pl.ceon.research.pigitos.pig.udf.MapEntriesToBag();
hbasedata = LOAD 'hbase://utable' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('u:*', '-loadKey true') AS (row:chararray, u:map[]);
extract = foreach hbasedata generate flatten(SUBSTRING($0,3,12)) as key, flatten(MapEntriesToBag($1)) as product;
dump extract ;
```

The 4th line of the above code is just an example on how you can use `MapEntriesTpBag` function from the UDF. You can do many more operations with the available functions which is described in that link.

Many thanks to Adam Kava from http://hakunamapdata.com

Answer (score -3):

In order to work with data in Pig, you need to know the schema of your data.  This is not the most elegant solution, but since you know you won't have more than 25 fields, quicker than finding an elegant solution to the problem would be to just one time type out all 25 fields, put them in a tuple, and then move on.

Comment: Actually, Pig can easily work with data that do not have schema, e.g.: a = load '/hello.tsv' USING TextLoader; will load the data without the schema. Regarding to original question I'm afraid you need to provide the schime while loading data from HBase(see: https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.1/api/org/apache/pig/backend/hadoop/hbase/HBaseStorage.html )